# How to convert a numerical value to a percentage of 100?

Tags: summation, arithmetic, percentages, cross-ratio

So, consider that are three tests a student has taken. The overall score is 100 points. The test has three sections.
Section 1 - 30 points
Section 2 - 30 points
Section 4 - 40 points

**Student scores**
Section 1 - 20 points
Section 2 - 20 points
Section 3 - 30 points

If I want to convert each section-wise score to a value out of 100, the average sum of converted values should still equal the sum of original scores. This was done using cross multiplication.

Section 1 - (student score X 100)/section score, i.e., 2000/30 = 66.667
Section 2 - 66.667
Section 3 - 75
Average = 69.4

Sum of Original Scores : 20+20+30 = 70

The average sum of conversions seems to differ by a small margin, and it varies all the time. This seems simple, but can anyone suggest a different formula other than cross multiplication? or do I need to add some corrections/factors?

Thanks

Comment: $2000/30$ is *not* equal to $66.667$. If you *round* the percentages then they may not add up to $100$ exactly.

Comment: @MartinR, yes, it will be 66.6667 something. But I have added some points to the description. Can you read and tell me again? Let me know if I'm clear with the description

Comment: Your question seems to boil down to asking why $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}\neq \frac{a+c}{b+d}$... Because these are not equal.  Why would they be?  You can see they are not equal by trying out some numbers as you have.  The correct identity should be $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=\frac{ad+bc}{bd}$

Comment: You are seeming to assume that the individual ratios can be averaged to give the same result of the final sum... this is very much incorrect.  Imagine an extreme scenario where you have two sections, the first section was worth only one point overall and the student scored a zero on it, and the other point worth 99 points and the student scored a full 99.  The students overall score would be $99$, not $50$, and this should be quick and easy to see and match intuition.  Where you got the idea to average the individual results, I do not know, but it is not based in reality.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, cross multiplication is what I did..It didn't work

Comment: @JMoravitz, thanks I will try it out. I'm not that great in maths

Comment: Further to JMoravitz's point, please refer to my answer [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/20772/372).

Comment: Rather than a true average... you want a *weighted average*... and those weights are the $30,30,40$ that you erroneously removed from the calculations in the first place.

Comment: Yes, it should have been weighted. I will check again. Thanks  @JMoravitz

Comment: @ryang, will check it out thanks

Comment: @JMoravitz, but do you think cross multiplication makes sense if we want the value to be converted out of 100? This is before taking the weighted average

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "cross multiplication" in this context.  The calculation as I see it should be $(\frac{20}{30}\times \frac{30}{100} + \frac{20}{30}\times \frac{30}{100}+\frac{30}{40}\times\frac{40}{100})\times 100$ if you insist on writing it like that... the $\frac{20}{30}$ being the value of the first and $\frac{30}{100}$ the weight of the first etc... but it is far easier to just write it as $20+20+30$ noting all of the cancellation.  "*Cross multiplication*" is to me what we do when we add two fractions, the $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=\frac{ad+bc}{bd}$ that I mentioned earlier

Comment: Yes, I suppose you can cross multiply to add those fractions together... but again... after simplification it is simply $20+20+30$ and no fractions appear and no cross multiplication is necessary, or you could have gotten it to a point where all have the same denominator where again no cross multiplication is necessary... $\frac{a}{d}+\frac{b}{d} = \frac{a+b}{d}$

Comment: Thanks..by cross multiplication I meant converting a student's score of 20 to 66.6667 for example. Because the student has a good score of 20 out of 30. Converting it to 66.6667 (which is out of 100) makes it seems the student has got a low score
@JMoravitz

Comment: 20 out of 30 is the same as 66 and a third out of 100.  Neither should seem like a better or worse score... they are the same